# RHEL7 gem install fails due to already installed zlib

Tags: ruby, rubygems, chef-infra, zlib, rhel7

I've found similar questions, but none of them deal with this exact problem. RHEL7, ec2 instance. I've already yum installed and rvm installed zlib. Still I cannot do a gem install

```
[root@host ~]# gem install knife-ec2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing knife-ec2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161027-19541-y7elcv.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You     may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib64
    --with-make-prog
```

==removed rest of error as it's standard and not relevant==

zlib has been installed via YUM as well as RVM :

```
[root@host ~]# rpm -qa | grep zlib
zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64
```

The log file doesn't say anything I can understand. I've never really worked with Ruby and I'm just doing this to get a cookbook tested in Chef.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You also need the development parts of zlib in order for the gem to be able to properly compile. `yum install zlib-devel` should help.

Comment: I think you might also need the `ruby-devel` package installed to get this going. Good luck!